# EAGLView transparency frames per second

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, transparency, eaglview, pixelformat

I have a Cocos2d project and I want a constant background throughout the app. In the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of its delegate, I have replaced the line:

```
[viewController setView:glView];
```

with

```
[[viewController view] addSubview:glView];
```

because I have added subviews to the RootViewController's view in it's initWithNib, and those changes are lost if the view is replaced with glView.

I have also changed the pixelFormat of glView from `kEAGLColorFormatRGB565` to `kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8`. When I make that change, glView becomes transparent and I can see through it, but the fps drops dramatically. If I don't make that change, the view doesn't become transparent, but I don't see the huge drop in fps. I'm talking about a significant drop in fps, from 59.0-60.0 to about 35.0-42.0.

I am using this code right below the addSubview line above to make the view transparent:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
director.openGLView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
director.openGLView.opaque = NO;
```

The last two lines are the culprits; commenting them out (both, not just one) causes the large drop in fps, while commenting out the `glClearColor` line has no effect on fps.

The whole applicationDidFinishLaunching method looks like this:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if(![CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //

    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]            
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 
                   depthFormat:0
                       ];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

    if(![director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    #if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
        [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    #else
        [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    #endif

    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];

    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [[viewController view] addSubview:glView];

    //***make glView transparent***
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    director.openGLView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    director.openGLView.opaque = NO;

    // make the View Controller a child of the main window
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // Removes the startup flicker
    [self removeStartupFlicker];

    // Run the intro Scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[MainMenu scene]];
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I can provide more code if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're testing this on a 1st or 2nd generation device, the drop in framerate is to be expected. Nothing you can do about it. These devices are heavily fillrate-limited, and a transparent 32-bit GL view is just asking too much of the device.

If this happens on a 3rd or even 4th generation device, then there's got to be something wrong but I couldn't begin to tell what that might be.

If you're testing the performance on the Simulator, don't. It's irrelevant.